# awk can not print an array and a position parameter at the same time

Tags: awk, control-m

awk can not print an array and a position parameter at the same time

```
hehe.txt —> 23402269,55
haha.txt —> 23402269,108147883084318723015500000055,1,0
```

--

Can not get a[$1] value

```
awk -F"," '{if(NR==FNR){a[$1] = $2}else{if($1 in a){print a[$1]" | "$0}}}' hehe.txt haha.txt
```

or

```
awk -F"," '{if(NR==FNR){a[$1] = $2}else{if($1 in a){printf("%s | %s\n",a[$1],$0)}}}' hehe.txt haha.txt
```

result

```
| 23402269,108147883084318723015500000055,1,0
```

--

using printf with %d, I can get correct result

```
awk -F"," '{if(NR==FNR){a[$1] = $2}else{if($1 in a){printf("%d | %s\n",a[$1],$0)}}}' hehe.txt haha.txt
```

result

```
55 | 23402269,108147883084318723015500000055,1,0
```

--

### Question: I wonder why, thanks.

Comment: You have Windows style line endings, ie. `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. Use `dos2unix` or add `BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"}` to your awk script.

Comment: I using mac book 10.14.2,
GNU Awk 4.2.1

Comment: @sagr, could you please try using `cat -v Input_file` and see if  `\r` characters are there?

Comment: file1: 23402269,108147883084318723015500000055,1,0^M

file2: 23402269,55^M

Comment: @sagr, see control M there,, that's  what James is mentioning about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned check if there are any control M characters if you need to remove them use following and then run your command.(In case you have `dos2unix` utility run it on your Input_file and get rid of control M characters)

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: Why does printf with %d work ?

Comment: It only prints the number part ignoring the `\r`, test it with `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%d\n","12ab"}'`

Comment: I don't really understand why is this caused by delimiters.